# PineScript - global scope variables are not obtained inside function

Tags: pine-script

for example, the following script:

```
//@version=4
study("sample")
func(val)=>
    label l1= label.new(bar_index, high, text=tostring(val[2]), style=label.style_circle) 
trigger_condition = barstate.islast
if(barstate.islast)
    func(close)
```

this always shows `nan` as result. What is the reason for that? neither changing `xyz_[2]` to `xyz[2]` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the visibility of a global variable in the function's scope, as the value the function is using is passed to it as an argument.

Your code doesn't work like you expect because you only call the function on the dataset's last bar, and since it's the first time it's called, there are no historic values of `val` to refer to when you create the label.

The solution is to execute the function on each bar. This code shows two equivalent methods of doing that, the second one being the most efficient. See comments in code:

```
//@version=4
study("sample")

func1(val)=>
    // Create label on first bar.
    var label l1 = label.new(bar_index, high, "", style=label.style_circle)
    // Redefine label's position and text on each bar.
    label.set_text(l1, tostring(val[2]))
    label.set_xy(l1, bar_index, high)

func2(val)=>
    // Track history of the values on every bar but do nothing else.
    _v = val[2]
    if barstate.islast
        // Create label on last bar only.
        l1 = label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(_v), style=label.style_circle)

func1(close)
```

[EDIT: 2020.09.15 15:26 — LucF]
Example of a third equivalent illustrating remarks in comments to answer:

```
func3(_val)=>
    if barstate.islast
        // Create label on last bar only.
        l1 = label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(_val), style=label.style_circle)

func3(close[2])
```

This method would also work because the current default for the history buffer of 250 ensures that a value exists for close at offset 2:

```
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(close[2]), style=label.style_circle)
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show two equivalent examples illustrating our point. Hope this helps clear things up. No, variables passed as arguments to functions are not passed as values, but as series. A series value, however, does not imply that the series' history is populated. In order to populate the history of the series used inside the function, it must be called on each bar.

Comment: here what i meant: https://pastebin.com/BQBifb3R

thanks for the answer . that should be mentioned  in pinescript documentations i think, when there is discussed about how "functions" work, with all these examples (including my pastebin example case)

Comment: The dynamic **is** explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks) in the usrman. Your pastebin example, again, does not work because you do not call the function on each bar, so there is no history in its local scope, whether for the `x` or `y` or any other variable you would use in that local scope.